# windows 7 and windows 8 works only first boot

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, bsod, formatting, nvidia-graphics-card

I recently bought and installed a SanDisk Ultra Plus 128gb SSD to replace my old 1TB Western Digital, now my PC fails to boot the second time I start it up.

I have tried a fresh install of Windows 7 and 8 on a Nvidia 580 GTX and a 285gtx. In all four cases, I have one screen with windows, a blank blue screen and nothing more.

If I reinstall Windows, the PC will work fine again. If I remove the video drivers through safe mode, they will auto install again and I will get a bluescreen on the next reboot.

Comment: More information about the changes you made is required to help. It should simply work. For instance what formats exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Well, so if it's a graphic card driver issue (as there are blue screens after every startup), then boot your pc into safe mode and when you uninstall the driver make sure that you check the option on the Uninstall Windows 'Remove driver software'. Download a suitable version of driver from your vendor and try rebooting again.
Please also open event viewer (search it in control panel) and see exactly what caused the issue. On the event viewer view event logs and then see information under every red or yellow bang.